# How to visualise the proportion of a boolean attribute being TRUE under brackets of a numeric attribute?

Tags: r, plot, visualization

Say in a data frame, X is a numeric attribute, Y is a boolean attribute.
How do I visualise the relationship between the two attributes, by dividing the X into k (say, 10) brackets according to the value of it, and plot a bar chart to show what's the proportion of Y under different value ranges of X, so the plot looks like this?

```
 % of Y
    ^
  1 |
0.8 |             ---
0.6 |             | |
0.4 |       ---   | |
0.2 | ---   | |   | |
  0 +-|-|---|-|---|-|---> X
      1-10 11-20 21-30
```

Also, I just don't know what is/is there a specific terminology of this kind of visualization problem, but it must be a commonly used visualisation technique. I also failed to think of, and find any more concise ways of expressing the above requirements. Can someone also help me to find a better way to describe this problem?

Comment: Thanks by stating "histogram" which helps. I have the idea of what I am looking for, but I don't know the terminology to even search for the right thing to research, as I stated in the question, which is the very question I want to ask.

Comment: search for the result, not the method. you want a plot of a frequency or count, search "plot counts in r" you get histograms and bar plots. then it is up to you to make the data: `barplot(table(mtcars$vs == 1, cut(mtcars$mpg, c(10, 20, 30, 40)))[2, ])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unusual aspect of this question is that unlike a typical histogram, the y axis represents proportions for one of the values of a second, binary variable. In essence, it's a graphical representation of the percentages from part of a two way table.

For example, we can calculate frequencies of V and straight engines (the `vs` variable) with a table, as noted in comments to the question.

```
mtcars$mpg_group <- cut(mtcars$mpg, c(10, 20, 30, 40))
table(mtcars$vs,mtcars$mpg_group)
> table(mtcars$vs,mtcars$mpg_group)
   
    (10,20] (20,30] (30,40]
  0      15       3       0
  1       3       7       4
```

In order to convert this to a barplot, we need to manipulate the data to calculate proportions. There are three different ways to calculate the proportions, including:

1. as a fraction of the total number of observations in the input data,
2. as a fraction of the total number of cars with a V engine, or
3. as a fraction of the total number of cars within an MPG range.

First we will calculate the proportions with V engines where the denominator is all cars in the data frame.

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(mtcars$vs,mtcars$mpg_group))
names(df) <- c("vs","mpg_group","count") # V engines
df$proportion <- df$count / sum(df$count)
plot_df <- df[as.numeric(df$vs)==1,]
```

At this point, `plot_df` contains the rows from the table printed above that correspond to V engines. We can now use `barplot()` to print a chart where the y axis represents the proportions of an `mpg_group` that have V shaped engines.

```
barplot(proportion ~ mpg_group,data = plot_df,ylim=c(0,1),
        main="mtcars: Cars with V Engines by MPG range")
```

...and the output:

[image]

To print a barplot where the denominator of the percentages is the the total number of cars with V engines, we adjust the code as follows.

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(mtcars$vs,mtcars$mpg_group))
names(df) <- c("vs","mpg_group","count") # V engines
plot_df <- df[as.numeric(df$vs)==1,]
plot_df$proportion <- plot_df$count / sum(plot_df$count)
barplot(proportion ~ mpg_group,data = plot_df,ylim=c(0,1),
        main="mtcars: Cars with V Engines by MPG range")
```

...and the output:

[image]

Finally, calculating the proportions given the number of cars in an MPG range is a bit more complicated, but can be done with a combination of `aggregate()` and `merge().

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(mtcars$vs,mtcars$mpg_group))
names(df) <- c("vs","mpg_group","count") # V engines
totals <- aggregate(count ~ mpg_group,data = df,FUN="sum")
names(totals)[2] <- "total"
plot_df <- merge(df,totals)
plot_df <- plot_df[as.numeric(df$vs)==1,]
plot_df$proportion <- plot_df$count / plot_df$total
barplot(proportion ~ mpg_group,data = plot_df,ylim=c(0,1),
        main="mtcars: V Engine cars within MPG range")
```

...and the output:

[image]

### Interpreting the plots

The first chart can be interpreted as follows: *46% of cars have MPG between 10 and 20 and V engines.*

The second chart can be interpreted as: *Of the 18 cars that have V engines, 83% of them have MPG between 10 and 20.*

The third chart can be interpreted as: *Of the 18 cars with MPG between 10 and 20, 83% have V shaped engines.*

Comment: Great, this answered my question in a very comprehensive manner. I have also found an alternative way of producing each of these 3 charts. Firstly generate the table as you did `t = table(mtcars$vs,mtcars$mpg_group)`. Then you can use `prop.table` to convert it into a table of proportions: `prop.table(t, NULL)` for the first chart in your case, `prop.table(t, 1)` for the second, `prop.table(t, 2)` for the third. Then just `plot(t[2,])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable that has fixed bins (like country of birth) you would use a bar chart.  The bars should have spaces between them.  If you have a variable that can take many possible values across a range, like age in years, you want a histogram.  The histogram puts the bins right next to each other to give the visual clue that the bins could be done using different ranges.

If you are just starting to learn statistics and visualization take a look at https://www.openintro.org/.  They have excellent materials for high school and university students (with solid R an SAS guides).